# ImportError with psutil eventhough 'pip3 show psutil' shows it is installed

Tags: python, linux, psutil

if I execute my py script with 'import psutil' I get the error "ImportError: No module named psutil". I realized if I use pip3 install psutil it installs it to /lib64/ and my other modules to /lib/ so I used --target and put in the path the other modules were in and removed it from /lib64/ but it still does not work. I am working on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I executed my script with 'python ...' and not 'python3 ...'

It works now